# Modern way managing string resources in a WinAPI project

Tags: c++, winapi, resources

At the moment I'm developing a windows service in C++ using the `winapi` and `boost`. Because it's a good style not to write strings in the source code (like "Service is started.") and because of the aspect of internationalization I'm looking after a technique to manage the messages/captions of my application.

I found an [code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/mctutorial.aspx) which describes the usage of the message compiler (mc.exe) in combination with resource files. But this way looks a little bit uncommon. The author wrote that the message compiler is a seldom used tool and the article is also pretty old. Because of that I would like to ask what's a modern way managing strings in a project which only relies on the windows API and boost.

I hope somebody could give me a hint.

Comment: FYI:  One string you DO want in the source code is:  "Can't load string resources"

Comment: Message Tables are normally for outside libraries/applications to use (the event viewer, library error message translation, etc. String tables are more often used internally in a process and allow string IDs up to 32K I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Windows applications, I suggest good old fashioned STRINGTABLEs in resource files, and using the [LoadString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API.

Services can also make use of the above, with a notable exception.  If your service needs to post messages to the Windows Event Log, then you'll need to use the message compiler to store such messages/format strings in your application as a resource.  [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (while terse) contains a summary of what needs to be done to support this.